# Why is kerberos collection not listing valid principals?

Tags: kerberos, klist

Each cache in folder:

```
$ ls -l ~/mycache
total 20
-rw------- 1 username username  998 Jan  1 10:18 a.REALM.cache
-rw------- 1 username username 1778 Jun  6 14:58 b.REALM.cache
-rw------- 1 username username 1665 Aug 31 12:22 c.REALM.cache
-rw------- 1 username username    4 Aug 31 15:50 primary
```

Kerberos environment variable:

```
$ echo $KRB5CCNAME
DIR:/home/username/mycache
```

By using `klist -l`:

```
Principal name                 Cache name
--------------                 ----------
```

But when changing to a specific cache it lists correctly:

```
$ echo $KRB5CCNAME
FILE:/home/username/mycache/c.REALM.cache
$ klist -l
Principal name                 Cache name
--------------                 ----------
kerberosID@REALM.COM           FILE:/home/username/mycache/c.REALM.cache (Expired)
```

I'm expecting that the cache collection lists each principal inside the collection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is with how the kerberos is initialized inside of the collection.
At the time of logging in it should use the option '-c':

```
$ kinit -kt file.keytab -c DIR::/home/username/mycache/tkt_c.REALM.cache
```

Afterwards by using `klist -l` or `klist -A` you can view the cached tickets:

```
$ klist -l
Principal name                 Cache name
--------------                 ----------
kerberosID@REALM.COM           DIR::/home/username/mycache/tkt_c.REALM.cache
```